# How to set collectionview cell width based on content?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a horizontal scrolling collectionview.The cell contains a label.I want to adjust the cell width based on the content of the label.How can this be achieved??Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of calling sizeforitem

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

 return CGSize(width: 100, height : 100)
}
```

You can set layout properties to auto resizing according to label content

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 30)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this func to calculate the label width

```
func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
     let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
     let size = self.size(attributes: fontAttributes)
     return size.width
}
```

Use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to set size of `collectionViewCell`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
let width = //calculated width of label from func
   return CGSize(width: width, height:requiredHeight)
}
```

Comment: In function widthOfString, what kind of class is that? In other words, where should I put the widthOfString function? I couldn't get the example code to work. Why isn't the width assigned a value? Should it be assigned to the value of widthOfString?

I think that a more complete answer would give an upvote.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Do you want help or suggesting me what to do in answer?

Comment: see my previous question on how to improve. In my world there is some information missing. I couldn't make the code to work.